# Outlook Add-In and Windows Form collaboration

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook-addin, windows-forms-designer

I'm developing an outlook add in that collaborates with SharePoint. I've added a new item to the Outlook add in: a Windows Form. When a button is being clicked in the Windows Form, I want to perform an action with Outlook, like this:

```
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
```

This isn't working, because I'm in the Windows Form instead of in the Outlook Add In. I'm not sure how to let those though collaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Add a new parameter to your WinForm constructor, to receive a reference to the Outlook Application object:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
.
.
.
public partial class MyWinForm : Form
{
    private Outlook.Application m_OutlookApp;

    public MyWinForm(Outlook.Application OutlookApp)
    {
        m_OutlookApp = OutlookApp;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Your add-in code to launch the form then becomes something like:

```
MyWinForm myWinForm = new MyWinForm(Application);

myWinForm.Show();
```

You can then use the Outlook Application within the WinForm:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace = m_OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Outlook Application object passed to the add-in during initialization is already intrinsically declared in the ThisAddIn class within your VSTO project.  You can access it from any other item in the project using `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application`.  You must use this object and not a new Outloook Application object because it won't be fully trusted as it wasn't passed to the add-in initialization by Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use something like this below,

```
var output = Globals.YourAddin.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
```

Hope this helps.